# Como puedo pasar un arreglo a un json

Tags: c#, json

Estoy tratando de armar un json con la siguiente estructura

```
{
"CardCode": "C003",
"DocumentLines": [
    {
        "ItemCode": "A004",
        "Quantity": "100",
        "TaxCode": "IVA",
        "UnitPrice": "500",
        "DiscountPercent": 10
    },
    {
        "ItemCode": "A005",
        "Quantity": "300",
        "TaxCode": "IVA",
        "UnitPrice": "250",
        "DiscountPercent": 10
    }
    
]
}
```

pero al momento de usar el código en mi clase me sale error en la parte donde declaro el arreglo ya que este json puede recibir multiples items para enviarlo al servidor

La clase que tengo es esta

```
public partial class Oferta
{
    [JsonProperty("CardCode")]
    public string CardCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("DocumentLines")]
    public List<DocumentLine> DocumentLines { get; set; }
}
public partial class DocumentLine
{
    [JsonProperty("ItemCode")]
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Quantity")]
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("TaxCode")]
    public string TaxCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("UnitPrice")]
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("DiscountPercent")]
    public decimal DiscountPercent { get; set; }
}
```

Y el codigo que uso para armar el json es este

```
 var oferta = new Oferta();
        oferta.CardCode = pedido.CodigoSAP_Cliente;
        foreach (var item in listaPedido)
        {
            
            oferta.DocumentLines = new List<DocumentLine>
            {
                new DocumentLine
                {
                    ItemCode = item.Codigo,
                    DiscountPercent = item.Descuento,
                    TaxCode = "IVA",
                    Quantity = item.Cantidad,
                    UnitPrice = item.Precio
                }
            };

        }
        string ofertaJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oferta, Formatting.Indented);
```

esto lo encontre por la web pero no me esta funcionando y he estado buscando y me sale cosas similares

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Me parece que los decoradores no son necesarios cuando la propiedad tiene el exactamente el mismo nombre (por lo menos yo no los uso nunca)

Esto:

```
public partial class Oferta
{
    [JsonProperty("CardCode")]
    public string CardCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("DocumentLines")]
    public List<DocumentLine> DocumentLines { get; set; }
}
```

Se puede escribir:

```
public partial class Oferta
{
    public string CardCode { get; set; }
    public List<DocumentLine> DocumentLines { get; set; }
}
```

2. La lista DocumentLines  está mal declara, la tienes que instanciar antes del for y dentro de él llenarla

```
 var oferta = new Oferta();
        oferta.CardCode = pedido.CodigoSAP_Cliente;
        oferta.DocumentLines = new List<DocumentLine>();
        foreach (var item in listaPedido)
        {
            oferta.DocumentLines.Add( 
                new DocumentLine
                {
                    ItemCode = item.Codigo,
                    DiscountPercent = item.Descuento,
                    TaxCode = "IVA",
                    Quantity = item.Cantidad,
                    UnitPrice = item.Precio
                }
            );

        }
```

```
    string ofertaJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oferta, Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: Nuevamente gracias por la ayuda